# How to write on a separate terminal using C in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, gnome-terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to invoke another terminal for output programmatically in C in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445645/how-to-invoke-another-terminal-for-output-programmatically-in-c-in-linux)

I am programming a client-server application and I want to create a debug window.

On the server side I want to print the incoming and outgoing communication on a separate terminal.
I am able to spawn a terminal through gnome-terminal but how to write on it and not on other terminals.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445645/how-to-invoke-another-terminal-for-output-programmatically-in-c-in-linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining idea of @ibid idea to what you want. Write to log file and than execute:

```
xterm -e tail "-f" log_file
```

This will span xterm , which executes "tai -f log file" command.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you for some reason really need to print to a terminal, I wouldn't bother, not just for a debug printout.

I would have the server print to a log file (remembering to flush it appropriately often) and then use `tail -f` in another terminal to follow it.  This has the added benefit of giving me a record of what the server debug-printed that I can examine at leisure.

Comment: okay another idea, what if I spawn system("xterm") and redirect all STDERR_FILENO to the new xterm, ill be able to achieve what i want, but how do i map STDERR_FILENO to the new xterm?

Comment: @ibid you could also write to a named pipe instead of a file

Answer (score 0):

The "correct" answer to this question is that you can write to /dev/ttyNUM... if you know the right tty number.

But that's only technical correctness, you should do something else. What you're trying to do is wrong.