# How to open new terminal through C program in linux

Tags: c, linux, unix, gnome-terminal

I have written client-sever code where I have many connections, let say each node represents different process on same machine. And to do that I have obviously use fork().

But now problem is that all results get displayed on same terminal.
I want to know is there any way such that after each `fork()` or process creation new terminal gets opened and all results get displayed for that process on particular terminal.

P.S: I have tried `system("gnome-terminal")`  but it just opens new terminal but all results get displayed again on same terminal only. All new terminals are just opens and remain  blank without any result.

Also I have gone through this link [How to invoke another terminal for output programmatically in C in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445645/how-to-invoke-another-terminal-for-output-programmatically-in-c-in-linux) but I don't want to run my program with parameters or whatever. Its should be just like `./test`

Here is my code:-

```
for(int i=0;i<node-1;i++)
  {
    n_number++;
    usleep(5000);
    child_pid[i]=fork();
    if(!child_pid[i])
    {
      system("gnome-terminal");
      file_scan();
      connection();          
      exit(0);
    }     
    if(child_pid[i]<0)
      printf("Error Process %d cannot be created",i);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<node-1;i++)
    wait(&status);
```

So basically what I want is for each process there should be new terminal displaying only that process information or result.

What I exactly want:

- After fork() I have some data related to say process 1 then I want its output to one terminal
- Same goes with each process. So its like if I have 3 process then there must be 3 terminals and each must display process related data only.

I know it can be doable using IPC(Inter Process Communication) but is there any other way around? I mean just 2-3 commands or so? Because I do not want to invest too much in coding this part.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How is the original process going to arrange to write to the terminal?  What process in the new terminal is going display the information you write?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I wish I remembered file descriptors and streams more, but couldn't you theoretically open a new terminal and redirect `stdout` to whatever file descriptor exists for that terminal? Hm I think I am misunderstanding terminals...

Comment: My suspicion/expectation is that in the absence of anything else, the terminal is set up with its own shell, and with its own (surprise) terminal (`/dev/ttyXXX` or `/dev/ptyXXX`).  So, some careful plumbing will likely be necessary so that the input for the terminal window comes from your process that wants to write to it, and you'll need a program (maybe `cat`?) to read that input and write to the terminal window.  I've not done it, so I don't know what the tricks are.  (Have you tried `man gnome-terminal`?)

Comment: Its like... after fork() I have some data related to say process 1 then I want its output to one terminal and same goes with each process. So its like if I have 3 process then there must be 3 terminal and each must display process related data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yeah I look into the {man gnome-terminal} haven't found anything interesting. Also trying to do this by using {system("xterm")}. But no luck till now. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you want something like that. This program is using the unix98 pseudoterminal (PTS), which is a bidirectional channel between master and slave. So, for each fork that you do, you will need to create a new PTS, by calling the triad posix_openpt, grantpt, unlockpt at master side and ptsname at slave side. Do not forget to correct the initial filedescriptors (stdin, stdout and sdterr) at each side.

Note that is just a program to prove the concept, so I am not doing any form of error check.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
  pid_t i;
  char buf[10];
  int fds, fdm, status;

  fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR);
  grantpt(fdm);
  unlockpt(fdm);

  close(0);
  close(1);
  close(2);

  i = fork();
  if ( i != 0 ) { // father
    dup(fdm);
    dup(fdm);
    dup(fdm);
    printf("Where do I pop up?\n");
    sleep(2);
    printf("Where do I pop up - 2?\n");
    waitpid(i, &status, 0);
  } else {  // child
    fds = open(ptsname(fdm), O_RDWR);
    dup(fds);
    dup(fds);
    dup(fds);
    strcpy(buf, ptsname(fdm));
    sprintf(buf, "xterm -S%c/2", basename(buf));
    system(buf);
    exit(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(buf, "xterm -S%c/2", basename(buf));` should be %s for `char *`.

Comment: why is `i==0`  the father. normaly the `PID==0` is the child process, right? An change you wanted to write `i!=0` ?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace from fork man page: _On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned  in the  child._ so, yes, if `i==0` you are in child process. In this example, the correct would be `i!=0`. Thanks